# Maven - SQLite - Missing database

Tags: sqlite, maven, netbeans

I'm new to maven and I'm trying to make my project work with an sqlite database.

Code works as a normal java project.

I made a Maven project with the exact same working code and added the dependacies in the pom.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, the Library.sqlite is in the root folder of the project (where it works as a normal java project)

**works in java, not in maven**

```
"jdbc:sqlite:‪Library.sqlite"
```

The error reads "[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database"

Since it's the same code as the java project, I'm sure there is no syntax error, so it must be something with the location of the Library.sqlite?

How can I make this work?

**SOLUTION**

It seems my program created a new empty Library.sqlite in my folder and that's why it couldn't find my tables. After deleting the original and editing the new one, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the same library as you and it seems to work fine for me. Take a look: https://github.com/ajorpheus/SqliteHelloWorld

Sample output after a successful build:

```
name = leo
id = 1
name = yui
id = 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it made me realise a naming conflict error!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted!